# How can I know how many provider hops there are in each SMS via SMPP?

Tags: sms, smpp

I use SMPP routes towards providers, which have others providers in order to send SMS until the local operator.
My question is... How can I know how many provider hops there are in each SMS via SMPP?
I mean, since the SMS is sent towards the next provider until the SMS is delivered in the handset, does exist any way to know how many hops there are? 
Could I add any information in the SMS in order to get this information?
I would like to get this information in order to know if the route is good or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

With standard SMPP it is not possible to know how many hops (i.e. SMS gateways and SMSCs) there are between your application and the handset.

Monitoring the latency between submission by your application and delivery to the handset can provide a hint at there being multiple hops. This approach isn't reliable as high latency could simply be a slow single hop rather than multiple hops.

Asking your immediate provider how they route your messages can provide some insight. If they send directly to an SMSC belonging to handset's mobile network operator then you know that it should only be a hop from you to the provider and then another from them to the MNO. Probes, or your own testing, can be used to confirm if your message is being routed directly to the handset's MNO. In such cases you will see an SMSC address (SMSC GT) in the receive SMS that belongs to the handset's MNO.

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the SMPP protocol to know the hops to the final SMSC that delivers your SMS to the destination mobile. Number of hops does necessarily account for delays in SMS delivery. 
If you will like to know if a certain route is good or not you could use other metrics like how many successful delivery reports have been received for SMSes sent via that route to build a table of good routes and bad routes.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly not part of the SMPP protocol. For sure your sms won't be delivered via SMPP only, but also via SS7. The performance could depend on so many factors ... I think the best way to evaluate a 'route' is ( as other have said) to build some metrics/kpi's yourself and analyze them.